# Get xcoms with a key from all tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have two Airflow tasks that are pushing `xcoms` with the same key `srcDbName`, but with different values. These two tasks are followed by a task that reads the `xcoms` with key `srcDbName` and prints their values. See the code below:

```
def _fill_facebook_task(ti):
    ti.xcom_push(key='srcDbName', value='SRC_PL_Facebook')

def _fill_trip_advisor_task(ti):
    ti.xcom_push(key='srcDbName', value='SRC_PL_TripAdvisor')

def _pm_task(ti):
    values = ti.xcom_pull(key='srcDbName')
    print(', '.join(values))

facebook = PythonOperator(
    task_id="fill-facebook",
    python_callable= _fill_facebook_task,
    dag=dag
)

tripAdvisor = PythonOperator(
    task_id="fill-trip-advisor",
    python_callable=_fill_trip_advisor_task,
    dag=dag
)

pm = PythonOperator(
    task_id="premises-matching",
    python_callable=_pm_task,
    dag=dag
)

facebook  >> pm
tripAdvisor >> pm
```

I expect the `pm` task should print

> SRC_PL_Facebook, SRC_PL_TripAdvisor

(or in a different order) because the [documentation for xcom_pull](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.2/_modules/airflow/models.html) states:

> :param task_ids: Only XComs from tasks with matching ids will be
> pulled. Can pass None to remove the filter.

Actually, it prints

> S, R, C, _, P, L, _, F, a, c, e, b, o, o, k

Is it possible to read all `xcoms` with a given key from all upstream tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read all of the xcoms you'd need to pass in all of the upstream task_instance names as an argument to `xcom_pull`. The documentation for the `xcom_pull` method definitely doesn't make that clear -- it only says:

```
If a single task_id string is provided, the result is the value of the most
recent matching XCom from that task_id. If multiple task_ids are provided, a
tuple of matching values is returned. None is returned whenever no matches
are found.
```

but it should also mention that if you don't pass any task_ids then `xcom_pull` will return only the first (if any) matching value that it finds. You can verify that behavior in the [code for airflow.models.taskinstance](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b1579530cf171b7484f471a9a011bc2ef4a1c83d/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L2209).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the source code, it's very helpful!